# How to record video and audio with MediaCodec and MediaMuxer

Tags: android, audio, video, android-mediacodec, mediamuxer

I am able to record(encode) video with the help of MediaCodec and MediaMuxer. Next, I need to work on audio part and mux audio with video with help of MediaCodec and MediaMuxer.

I am facing two problems:

1. How to encode audio with MediaCodec. Do I need to encode audio and
   video in separate threads?
2. How can I pass audio and video data to MediaMuxer (as
   writeSampleData() method takes only one type of data at a time)?

I referred to [MediaMuxerTest](http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/#MediaMuxerTest) but it is using MediaExtractor. I need to use MediaCodec as video encoding is done with MediaCodec. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Any suggestion or advice will be very helpful as there is no proper documentation available for these new APIs.

**Note:**

1. My app is targeting to API 18+ (Android 4.3+).
2. I have referred [Grafika](https://github.com/google/grafika) for video encoding.

Comment: Any code samples? I need to add audio as well.

Comment: please refer this link : **[AudioVideoRecordingSample](https://github.com/saki4510t/AudioVideoRecordingSample)**

Answer (score 5):

1. No, you don't necessarily need a separate thread for audio, just use two separate MediaCodec instances.
2. The first parameter of `writeSampleData` is `trackIndex`, which allows you to specify which track each packet corresponds to. (By running `addTrack` twice, once for each track, you get two separate track IDs.)