# How to save front and back camera footage in the same file after being recorded simultaneously?

Tags: android, android-camera

I am having a hard time to figure out how to save footage from both front and back camera at the same time in the same file.

At the moment I have both cameras preview on screen working perfectly but I would like to whenever I press record button to capture those frames until I press it again to stop. Then, it should be saved together locally on device.

Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: The only way that i can see it possible is using AsyncTask or Threads, so the Tread A record the front camera, and the Tread B record the Back

Answer (score 0):

Recording preview frames coming from both cameras is not different from any other case of [recording video that is through MediaCodec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26628677/how-to-record-video-and-audio-with-mediacodec-and-mediamuxer). You cannot use MediaRecorder.

Comment: The thing is how would I merge them? I don't want to create one file for each camera. I would like to have both instances in one file. Like if I was recording the screen but without UI elements (buttons, text)...

Comment: You must prepare a single merged YUV frame every time. There are no ready-to-use tools to create such merged frame. You will end up copying the two frames pixel-by-pixel (NEON and GPU may help to some extent).

Comment: I have literally no idea how to do this. Do you know any resource out there to help me out? Where can I learn this?